# Eclipse how to refactor variable names?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, refactoring

In my 15 years old java project, Standard Java Conventions are not respected, and first letter of variable names is often capitalized.

I would like to refactor my project to lower case first letter of variables names, especially in method signatures :

```
public void creerProfil(String CodeProfil, Profil ProfilACreer) throws Exception {
...
}
```

should be :

```
public void creerProfil(String codeProfil, Profil profilACreer) throws Exception {
...
}
```

If you have any idea of plugin which could do that, I would be glad to hear it  :)

Answer (score 22):

If you are on windows/ubuntu platform use `alt+shift+R` or on mac use `command+option+r`. It will refactor all the occurences where **that** variable is used.

To get the list of shortcuts available in eclipse, use `ctrl+shift+L` in windows/ubuntu and `command+shift+l` in mac.

Comment: Where option was "alt" on my mac keyboard

Comment: Works (for me) on Linux too.

Answer (score 6):

You can Also Press Alt+Shift+R in Eclipse to refactor on variable.

Answer (score 5):

No plugins needed, rightclick on the variable name, then "refactor" -> "rename". However, never tried before, I don't know how reliable it is among the whole project.

Comment: Generally, as long as there are no errors in the affected files this works like a charm.

Comment: Well, a project can contain EJB, JSP, different ORM mapping files... I mean, long live Eclipse and its features, but better keeping both eyes open.

Answer (score 4):

In Eclipse Neon, I do the following to rename a variable across the project:

1. Go to `Search->File...`
2. Enter the name of the variable in `Containing text:`
3. Click `Replace...` which is located at the bottom of the dialog box.
4. A new dialog box opens. There, put the variable name you want to replace with in `With...` labelled text box.
5. To preview, where the changes will be reflected, click on `Preview >`
6. Once, you are sure, click `OK`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a good idea, using "whole word" and "Case sensitive" can do the job as long as the variable have not the same name as the type.

Answer (score 2):

To answer you simply, right Click variable name > refactor > rename. But you have to do it variable by variable.I case you want to find all the violation of variable names at one go, use checkstyle [Checkstyle naming convention](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_naming.html)

Checkstyle will give you list of all the places code convention is not followed and then you can refactor.

Comment: Of course I can't rename each variable othewise it will take me ages. Checkstyle seems a good option, I tried Eclipse-cs plugin which detects all the naming convention violations with this message : "Parameter name 'Toto' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'."  Unfortunately the option "Apply Checkstyle fixes" does not work on this kind of violation... :-/

Answer (score 2):

Refactor within a file: Use Alt+Shift+R

Refactor within multiple files: Use Alt+Shift+R two times (To make it simple, hold Alt+Shift and press R two times).

This behaviour works with Eclipse Oxygen, Windows.
Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [eclipse docs](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-menu-refactor.htm) for Rename refactoring:-

> Renames the selected element and (if enabled) corrects all references to the elements (also in other files).
>
> Available: Methods, method parameters, fields, local variables, types, type parameters, enum constants, compilation units, packages, source folders, projects and on a text selection resolving to one of these element types
>
> Shortcut:  Alt + Shift + R

For Refactoring a method's signature/parameters:-

> Changes parameter names, parameter types, parameter order and updates all references to the corresponding method. Additionally, parameters and thrown exceptions can be removed or added and method return type and method visibility can be changed.
>
> Available: Methods or on text selection resolving to a method
>
> Shortcut:  Alt + Shift + C

Answer (score 1):

Simply click on the variable name that you want to refactor, use the command `Shift+Alt+T` and you will be getting the options like rename , move, change signature.

Answer (score 0):

To select a variable automatically then rename, use the following shortcut.

CTRL+ 2 R

Change or modify the variable.
[image]

Fedora 38 Linux

Eclipse Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)